# How to test a parallel port C# application?

Tags: c#, hardware, parallel-port

I am implementing a simple C# application that controls some leds (on/off) through the parallel port. My problem now is that I would like to test the application and monitor the behavior of the signals that I send out.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have like a virtual parallel port address on my windows PC and monitor this port ? Note that I don't have a LPT port in my laptop, this application will be executed on another PC.

Comment: How are you implementing this? There is no direct port access (i.e. `in` and `out` instructions) under all modern versions of Windows. Are you using something like `inpout32.dll`?

Comment: Have you tried [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+parallel+port+driver&oq=virtual+parra&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8603j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?  This is the [4rd result](http://softadvice.informer.com/Free_Virtual_Lpt_Port.html)

Comment: @paqogomez, yes I searched on google before I ask here. I tried this and the application crashes "Stopped Working" for some reason. Mayb because I have windows 8 64 bit not 32.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your basic parallel port operations in a class that implements an interface. Then use constructor injection to provide an implementation of your parallel port interface to any class that needs to use a parallel port. That way, you can mock out a fake parallel port implementation to provide whatever sort of data you want to use for the purposes of your unit tests.